# Why is my Android app showing up blank and then crashing?

Tags: android, android-fragments, crash

> **Moved** from Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56123/why-is-my-android-app-showing-up-blank-and-then-crashing

Every time I try to run my Android app, it shows the title bar with no content below it. After two minutes or so, it crashes. Here's the logcat:

> http://pastebin.com/UFKeywgC

I know the problem stems from me trying to use a fragment structure for the first time. Here's my code:

### TipCalculator.java

```
/* My verion of the Deitel Tip Calculator */
package org.bh.tipcalculator2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class TipCalculator extends Activity {
    // constants used when saving/restoring state
    private static final String BILL_TOTAL     = "BILL_TOTAL";
    private static final String CUSTOM_PERCENT = "CUSTOM_PERCENT";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tip_calculator);
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tip_calculator, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private double currentBillTotal;      // Bill as entered by the user
        private int currentCustomPercent;     // Custom tip % as set by user
        private EditText billEditText;        // Bill input widget
        private EditText tip10EditText;       // 10% tip output
        private EditText tip15EditText;       // 15% tip output
        private EditText tip20EditText;       // 20% tip output
        private EditText tipCustomEditText;   // ##% tip output
        private EditText total10EditText;     // 10% total output
        private EditText total15EditText;     // 15% total output
        private EditText total20EditText;     // 20% total output
        private EditText totalCustomEditText; // ##% total output
        private TextView customTipTextView;   // Custom tip % output

        public PlaceholderFragment() {

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (savedInstanceState == null)
            {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                        .commit();
                currentBillTotal = 0;
                currentCustomPercent = 18;
            }
            else
            {
                currentBillTotal = savedInstanceState.getDouble(BILL_TOTAL);
                currentCustomPercent = savedInstanceState.getInt(CUSTOM_PERCENT);
            }
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tip_calculator, container, false);

            tip10EditText =       (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tip10EditText);
            tip15EditText =       (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tip15EditText);
            tip20EditText =       (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tip20EditText);
            tipCustomEditText =   (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tipCustomEditText);
            total10EditText =     (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.total10EditText);
            total15EditText =     (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.total15EditText);
            total20EditText =     (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.total20EditText);
            totalCustomEditText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.totalCustomEditText);
            customTipTextView =   (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.customTipTextView);

            billEditText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.billEditText);
            //System.out.print(billEditText);
            billEditText.addTextChangedListener(billEditTextWatcher);

            SeekBar customSeekBar = (SeekBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.customSeekBar);
            customSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(customSeekBarListener);
            return rootView;
        }

        /**
         * Calls {@link #updateStandard()} and then {@link #updateCustom()}.
         *
         * @see #updateStandard()
         * @see #updateCustom()
         */
        public void updateAll()
        {
            updateStandard();
            updateCustom();
        }

        public void updateStandard()
        {
            calculateTipAndTotal(tip10EditText, total10EditText, .1);
            calculateTipAndTotal(tip15EditText, total15EditText, .15);
            calculateTipAndTotal(tip20EditText, total20EditText, .2);
        }

        public void updateCustom()
        {
            customTipTextView.setText(currentCustomPercent + "%");
            calculateTipAndTotal(tipCustomEditText, totalCustomEditText, currentCustomPercent);
        }

        public void calculateTipAndTotal(EditText tipEditText, EditText totalEditText, double tip)
        {
            tipEditText  .setText(String.format("%.02f", currentBillTotal * tip));
            totalEditText.setText(String.format("%.02f", currentBillTotal * (tip + 1)));
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
        {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

            outState.putDouble(BILL_TOTAL, currentBillTotal);
            outState.putInt(CUSTOM_PERCENT, currentCustomPercent);
        }

        private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener customSeekBarListener =
                new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                        currentCustomPercent = seekBar.getProgress();
                        updateCustom();
                    }

                    @Override public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){}
                    @Override public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){}
                }
                ;

        private TextWatcher billEditTextWatcher =
                new TextWatcher()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        try
                        {
                            currentBillTotal = extractDouble(s);
                        }
                        catch (NumberFormatException ex) // if we still didn't get a number
                        {
                            currentBillTotal = 0;
                        }

                        updateAll();
                    }
                    @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
                    @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable){}
                }
                ;

        /**
         * Attempts to extract the first double found. This ideally works with percents, currency
         * notation, and other formats where the double is surrounded by delimiters and text, but is
         * not interrupted by it.<br/>
         *<br/>
         * A double may look like any one of these, where {@code #} represents any number of digits 0
         * through 9:
         *
         * <ul>
         *     <li>{@code #}</li>
         *     <li>{@code .#}</li>
         *     <li>{@code #.#}</li>
         * </ul>
         *
         * @param possibleDouble a character sequence that might contain a double
         *
         * @return the extracted double
         *
         * @throws java.lang.NumberFormatException if a double could not be found
         */
        public static double extractDouble(CharSequence possibleDouble)
        {
            /**
             * Matches at least one digit, optionally preceded by a radix point, optionally preceded by
             * any number of digits
             */
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([0-9]*\\.)?[0-9]+").matcher(possibleDouble);
            matcher.find();
            return Double.parseDouble(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

### activity_tip_calculator.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TipCalculator"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="org.bh.tipcalculator2.TipCalculator$PlaceholderFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentTipCalculator"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_tip_calculator" />
</FrameLayout>
```

### fragment_tip_calculator.xml

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".TipCalculator$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:stretchColumns="@string/tableLayoutStretchColumns">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/billTotalLabel"
            android:id="@+id/billTextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/billEditText"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:text="@string/zeroCurrency"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:editable="true"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
            android:hint="@string/billTotalHint"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <!--NumberPicker
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/billNumberPicker"
            android:layout_span="3" /-->
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tipTextLabel"
            android:id="@+id/tipLabelTextView"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/tip10EditText"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:focusable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:enabled="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:editable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:longClickable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:clickable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
            android:text="@string/zeroCurrency" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/tip15EditText"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:focusable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:enabled="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:editable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:longClickable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:clickable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
            android:text="@string/zeroCurrency" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/tip20EditText"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:focusable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:enabled="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:editable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:longClickable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:clickable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
            android:text="@string/zeroCurrency" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tenPercent"
            android:id="@+id/tenTextView"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fifteenPercent"
            android:id="@+id/fifteenTextView"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/twentyPercent"
            android:id="@+id/twentyTextView2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/totalTextLabel"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/total10EditText"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="@string/zeroCurrency"
            android:focusable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:enabled="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:editable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:longClickable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:clickable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/total15EditText"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="@string/zeroCurrency"
            android:focusable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:enabled="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:editable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:longClickable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:clickable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/total20EditText"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="@string/zeroCurrency"
            android:focusable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:enabled="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:editable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:longClickable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:clickable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/spacerTableRow"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/customTextLabel"
            android:id="@+id/customTextView"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark" />

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/customSeekBar"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:indeterminateOnly="false"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:max="200"
            android:progress="18" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/customTipReadoutPlaceholder"
            android:id="@+id/customTipTextView"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/tipTextLabel"
            android:id="@+id/tipCustomTextView"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/tipCustomEditText"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:focusable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:enabled="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:editable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:longClickable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:clickable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
            android:text="@string/zeroCurrency" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/totalTextLabel"
            android:id="@+id/totalCustomTextView"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/totalCustomEditText"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="@string/zeroCurrency"
            android:focusable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:enabled="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:editable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:longClickable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:clickable="@bool/outputEditable"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: You're out of memory.  Use a heap profiler and find where you're leaking memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
 public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
            currentBillTotal = 0;
            currentCustomPercent = 18;
        }
```

When you create the view for the `PlaceholderFragment`, you're actually creating **another** `PlaceholderFragment` and adding it too. This will keep running and consuming memory until it's completely exhausted (and crashes).

In short, you should remove that part. The fragment has already been added.

Comment: Thanks! It seems so obvious now!
Should I move it to `TipCalculator#onCreate`?

Comment: @Supuhstar Shouldn't be necessary there either. It's already in the xml layout.